# How to read a excel CSV file (comma separated value) in Java Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, excel, csv

**The objective:** Create an object oriented Graphical Java Application that program that will: Read a CSV ( comma separated value) file that consists of student names (first name, lastname), IDs and initial marks for content and delivery (use -1 values for un-evaluated students.

This is my Code that I have but when I click on the Select File.. It says "Expected firstName, lastName, ID, Content and Delivery" when it really should open the file and read the data. But for somehow its not working. 
enter image description here

Below is a my code:

private class ChooseFileListener implements ActionListener {

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
  Section<Student> section;

  JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
  FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                                                               "CSV file", "csv");
  fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);
  int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
  if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    if (selectedFile != null) {
      section = createNewSection(selectedFile);
      loadStudents(section, selectedFile);
      System.out.print(selectedFile);
}
}
}
}

public void RandomStudent(){
ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
max = (students.size()-1);
int x = (int) Math.random()* students.size();
System.out.println(x);
}


private Section<Student> createNewSection(File selectedFile) {
String filename = selectedFile.getName();
Section<Student> section = new Section<Student>(filename);
return section;
}


private void loadStudents(Section<Student> section, File selectedFile) {
Scanner in;
int MAX_COMMAS = 5;
try {
  in = new Scanner(selectedFile);
  String line = "";
  String[] studentData;
  in.nextLine();
  while (in.hasNext()) {
    line = in.nextLine();
    studentData = line.split(",");
    if (studentData.length == MAX_COMMAS) {
      section.addStudent(new Student(studentData[0],studentData[1],
                                     Integer.valueOf(studentData[2]), 
                                     Integer.valueOf(studentData[3]),
                                     Integer.valueOf(studentData[4])));
    } else {
      throw new Exception(
                          "Invalid file format. \nExcepted: firstname, lastname, id, content, delivery");
    }
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
}
}
}
```

**I nOW HAVE created another class Nameed Section:**

package patel.Jainam;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Section {

```
 private String data;
 private String FirstName;
 private String LastName;
 private int studentID;
 private int ContentMark;
 private int DeliveryMark;

 private ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

 public void FileData(String First, String Last, int ID, int Content, int Delivery){
      this.FirstName = First;
      this.LastName = Last;
      this.studentID = ID;
      this.ContentMark = Content;
      this.DeliveryMark = Delivery;
     }

public String setFirst(String First){
      return First;
}

 public String setLast (String Last){
     return Last;
 }
 public int setstudentID (int ID) {
     return ID;
 }
 public int setContentMark (int Content) {
     return Content;
 }
 public int setDeliveryMark (int Delivery) {
     return Delivery;
 }   

 public Section(String data) {
  this.data = data;
 }

 public void addStudent(Student student) {
  students.add(student);
 }
```

}

Comment: Note Before all the Code.. i created many buttons and labels and all that but I haven't included it because it's too long.

Comment: Does your csv file end with an extra (blank) line? That would cause the exception to be thrown.

Comment: Nope. it doesn't. I tried that before but It didn't work.

Comment: try using one of csv file readers, [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/), [apache-commons-csv](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/),...

Comment: Thanks but I Can't use OpenCSV because the file should automatically open when Its clicked on the "Select File" button. So it should just read and write all the information besides its corresponding label.

Comment: Don't get your point here. Any CSV parsing package will work like a filter on the fie you give. It would change the implementation of `loadStudents()` such that you need not worry about parsing the fields yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you check for `MAX_COMMAS`, but ou are checking this against the number of fields. This value will always be 5 for a correctly formatted file. So, you are ensuring to get to the else part of your code and always throw.

What you would want to express like is:

```
if (studentData.length != MAX_COMMAS)
```